# material Ui table rows not getting updated on set state

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, material-ui, setstate

I am passing the content to my material Ui table using props. When I pass the props explicitly it works. But I need to fetch the props from fire store database and then pass it to table. So, I am using use Effect to get the rows on page load. but when I try to set the rows using set state it doesn't show on the table (Material UI component).

```
function Notice () {
  return (
    <div>
      <Table rows= {[{Title: "ABC", A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 4}]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Above works perfectly.

```
function Notice() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
  const loadRows = () => {
    getDocs(collection(db, "notice"))
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        const tempRows = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          var fields = doc.data();
          tempRows.push({Title: fields.subject, A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 4});
        });
        setRows(tempRows);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    loadRows();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Table rows={rows} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This doesn't work. The console shows no error, and my table is empty. I have tried moving the function load Rows definition inside use effect to no avail. I consoled the temp rows before calling set state and it printed correctly.

```
function Notice() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
  const [newProp, setNewProp] = useState([]);

  const loadRows = () => {
    getDocs(collection(db, "notice"))
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        const tempRows = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          var fields = doc.data();
          tempRows.push({Title: fields.subject, A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 4});
        });
        setRows(tempRows);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    loadRows();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(rows);
    setNewProp(rows);
  }, [rows]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Table rows={newProp} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have also tried above using two use effects. The console printed shows the fetched rows correctly. Still the table is empty.

Answer (score 0):

please try the following version :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

 function Notice() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
  const loadRows = async () => {
  try {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'notice'));
    const tempRows = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      var fields = doc.data();
      tempRows.push({ Title: fields.subject, A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 4 });
    });
    setRows(tempRows);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
loadRows();
}, []);
 return (
<div>
  {/* Ensure the Table component receives the rows prop */}
  <Table rows={rows} />
</div>);}
```

Comment: I tried the above. Stil no result. The table displayed is empty. I also consoled the rows from props inside the table component. it initially is [] and then shows the correct value on console. but the displayed table is empty.